# java Null Pointer Exception in creating Android Widgets

Tags: java, android

I am writing a piece of code for my Android Phone which will create a list of `WifiDevices` in the area using its `personal scan`.

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I am creating a list.

My code goes follows:

```
public static synchronized void addDevice(DeviceInformation device, View v, Context con, boolean bool, int type) throws IOException {
    Log.v("addDevice", "Called");
    if (bool) {
        TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.DeviceList);
        LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(con);
        TextView tv = new TextView(con);
        System.out.println(v.toString());
        tv.setLayoutParams(layout);
        tr.setLayoutParams(layout);
        String message;
        Log.v("addDevice","Device Timeout");
        switch(type) {
            case 1:
                computerEnd = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                raspberryEnd = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                flyportEnd = true;
                break;
        }
        if (computerEnd && raspberryEnd && flyportEnd) {
            if (rowCounter > 0) {
                message = "No More Devices";
            } else {
                message = "No Devices Found"; 
            }
            tv.setText(message);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            if (rowCounter % 2 == 0) {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            } else {
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            tv.setVisibility(1);
            tr.addView(tv);
            tb.addView(tr); //This is line number 131
        }
    } else {   
        TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.DeviceList);
        LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(con);
        TextView tv = new TextView(con);

        tv.setLayoutParams(layout);
        tr.setLayoutParams(layout);

        Log.v("addDevice", "Received");
        String textToDisplay = device.getDeviceTypeString() + "\n" + device.getIPAddress(); //Write the text to display
        tv.setText(textToDisplay);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Drawable img;
        if (device.getDeviceType() == 1) {
            img = con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pc);
        } else if (device.getDeviceType() == 2) {
            img = con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.raspberry);
        } else {
            img = con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flyport);
        }
        img.setBounds(0,0,70,45);
        tv.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, img, null);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //empty
            }
        });
        if (rowCounter % 2 == 0) {
            tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        } else {
            tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        rowCounter++;
        Log.v("Result", "Device Added");
    }
}
```

My Logcat error:

```
05-11 05:25:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(30710): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20873
05-11 05:25:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(30710): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 05:25:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(30710):    at com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DeviceManagerWindow.addDevice(DeviceManagerWindow.java:131)
05-11 05:25:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(30710):    at com.connection.NetworkScanListenerRaspberry.run(NetworkScanListenerRaspberry.java:62)
05-11 05:25:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(30710):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

This is how this particular code is reached:

This code calls a `Thread` which in return calls this method.

```
public void searchDevice(View view) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        Thread ComputerListener = new Thread(new NetworkScanListenerComputer(getApplicationContext(),view));
        ComputerListener.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("Exception:","Exception from SearchDevice Method"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

This the code for the Thread:

```
package com.connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.devicecontrolpanel.DeviceManagerWindow;

public class NetworkScanListenerComputer implements Runnable
{
    View thisView;
    Context thisContext;
    MulticastSocket socket = null;
    DatagramPacket inPacket = null;
    byte[] inBuf;
    public NetworkScanListenerComputer(Context con, View v)
    {
        thisView = v;
        thisContext = con;
        try
        {
            socket = new MulticastSocket(WifiConstants.COMPUTER_RECV_PORT);
            socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NETWORK_ADDR));
            inBuf = new byte[1024];
            inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
            socket.setSoTimeout(1*60*1000);
        }
        catch(Exception ioe)
        {
            Log.v("Exeception:","Computer Listener Exception"+ioe);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Listening...");
                socket.receive(inPacket);
                System.out.println("Received");
                String msg = new String(inBuf, 0, inPacket.getLength());
                DeviceInformation device = new DeviceInformation(1, msg, inPacket.getAddress().toString());

                DeviceManagerWindow.addDevice(device, thisView, thisContext, false, 1);

                Log.v("Received:","Received Computer From :" + inPacket.getAddress() + " Msg : " + msg);
                //System.out.write(inPacket.getData(),0,inPacket.getLength());
                System.out.println();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Exception:","During Receiving Computer: "+e.toString());
            try
            {
                DeviceManagerWindow.addDevice(null, thisView, thisContext, true, 1);
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                Log.v("Exception:", "Computer End Error: " +e1);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing the `view` and the `context` of the application which is again redirected to the `static method` because static method cannot make use of them.

I figured out the *problem... it is saying..* **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

That is the thread (`DeviceManagerWindow.java`) which created the view can only access `R.id.deviceList`. So what should I do if I want to access it.?

Comment: Which line is line 131?  That will go a long way towards determining what is `null` here.

Comment: Null pointer exception is quite common. Check if your `DeviceManagerWindow` instance is null. And I think the codes you post is not the cause of your exception. Tell us more about your code will be helpful

Comment: `tb` is null because `findViewById()` didn't find this view.

Comment: Check if `DeviceList` is in that `view` that you pass

Comment: +1 not sure why this gets a downvote. Relevant code, logcat, indicated which line has the error, description of what the OP has going on...all the makings of a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to update the `UI` from a background `Thread`. You could use `runOnUiThread()` but even easier I think would be to make that `Thread` an `AsyncTask`. Then you can do all of the network stuff in the `doInBacground()` and update the `UI` in `onPostExecute()`

If this is a separate file and not an inner class then you can just pass `context` to the constructor so you can update the `UI`. Or you can return a value which tells the calling `Activity` to do something or not. I'm not sure but it looks like you might be calling this one at a time. If so, I would suggest calling a task to get all of the devices in the background while the `UI` is doing something and add them to a list from there. The other thing is it looks like you may have an infinite `loop` with `while true` in your `Thread`. If this is the case, I would change that to something that listens for a value to change. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing you should do is debugging, to get exactly where is your null pointer exception. But if you take a good look at your code, then there are two very probable possibilities for having a null pointer exception, the first one could be:

```
TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.DeviceList);
```

because View v didn't found any view with id == "DeviceList"

or here:

```
if(device.getDeviceType()==1)
```

because device is getting passed in your method "null".
So, check out these two.
Good Luck

Comment: There are plenty of places there that could produce a `NPE` but only one of those could be the culprit with the logcat posted by the OP

Comment: That's closer but `device.getDeviceType()` can't be the issue because it is in a different block than where the `NPE` is occurring. According to the logcat, the error occurs in the `if` block but that code is in the `else` block

Comment: I figured out the problem... it is saying..

`Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

That is the thread (`DeviceManagerWindow.java`) which created the `view` can only access `R.id.deviceList`. So what should I do if I want to access it.?